# Google Face Detection crashing when converting to image and trying to detect face

Tags: ios, swift3, camera, face-detection, google-ios-vision

I am creating a custom camera with filters. When I add the following line it crashes without showing any exception.

//Setting video output

```
func setupBuffer() {
    videoBuffer = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoBuffer?.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    videoBuffer?.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA)]
    videoBuffer?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    captureSession?.addOutput(videoBuffer)
}


public func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if connection.videoOrientation != .portrait {
        connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    }
        guard let image = GMVUtility.sampleBufferTo32RGBA(sampleBuffer) else {
            print("No Image ")
            return
        }

    pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!, options: CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)as! [String : Any]?)

    CameraView.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectProcess")
    CameraView.filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let cgimg = CameraView.context.createCGImage(CameraView.filter!.outputImage!, from: ciImage.extent)

    DispatchQueue.main.async  {
        self.preview.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    }
}
```

But it's crashing on -

```
  guard let image = GMVUtility.sampleBufferTo32RGBA(sampleBuffer) else {
                print("No Image ")
                return
            }
```

When I pass image which is created from CIImage, it doesn't recognize the face in the image. 
Complete code file is **https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1ewd1sh18h3ezj/CameraView.swift.zip?dl=0**

[image]

Comment: You should set up an exception breakpoint to catch the exact error message.

Comment: I added that but it's crashing somewhere in the framework. I don't have access to code.

Comment: Have you determined whether the issue is with the framework itself or with the way you call the framework? Try to run one of the sample apps for the framework.

Comment: It's running fine. And I just copy paste that code in my project

Comment: Why are you using the main queue to handle outputsampleBuffer??

Comment: If I handle it in background queue CPU will try to complete the task in the main queue and ignore this. I created the new queue with the highest priority and set video buffer in that queue. This will keep it on high priority to deliver frames. And frame rate is also increased and drop frame count decrease.

Comment: @ChanWarde have you figured this out? did you base in Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Hi @Pei , yes i figured it and I am working in swift 3.

Comment: Wow, awesome. What's the issue? I just experience the same issue for a few days.

Comment: @pie see my answer for this. And if it help you please upvote it.

Comment: hm... actually that's what i'm doing already but there's no luck with it.

Comment: Oh then wait i'll send you file. Share your email address. Or try with this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B50nVFcsGrXgUnFHbzFOSndVYTQ/view

Comment: I've ended up setting session preset to medium rather than photo or higher. There should be a memory leak in the library itself.

Comment: You can set other preset, there are many other preset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create separate queue for buffer.

```
 fileprivate var videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
```

2)  Setup buffer with this

```
        let videoBuffer = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoBuffer?.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        videoBuffer?.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
        videoBuffer?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue ) //
        captureSession?.addOutput(videoBuffer)
```